# Character subtraction in String

Tags: java

Here is the code snippet i am trying to figure out whats happening

```
String line = "Hello";
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        char character = line.charAt(i);
        int srcX = 0;
            if (character == '.') {
            }else{
                srcX = (character - '0') * 20;

                System.out.println("Character is " + (character - '0') +"     " + srcX);
            }
        }
```

and executing that code will result to this

```
Character is 24     480
Character is 53     1060
Character is 60     1200
Character is 60     1200
Character is 63     1260
```

How a character minus the string which is  "0" result in integer?? and where does the system base its answer to have 24,53,60,60,63?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to subtract characters because `char` is an integer type.

The value of a character is the value of its codepoint (more or less, the details are tricky due to Unicode and UTF-16 and all that).

When you subtract the character '0' from another character, you are essentially subtracting 48, the code point of the character DIGIT ZERO.

So, for example, something like '5' - '0' would evaluate to 53 - 48 = 5.  You commonly see this pattern when "converting" strings containing digits to numeric values.  It is not common to subtract '0' from a character like 'H' (whose codepoint is 72), but it is possible and Java does not care.  It simply treats characters like integers.

Comment: Unicode is the name of a character set, just like ASCII.  ASCII is a very small character set with only 127 characters; Unicode is the character set used by Java and has hundreds of thousands of defined characters.  And for what it's worth the codepoints of characters within ASCII are the same as they are in Unicode.  '0' has codepoint 48 in both sets.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ascii.cl/

'0' is 48 in ascii
'H' is 72.

Therefore 72-48 gives you 24